# 2x2 linear mixed effects model

Tags: r, lme4

I am not sure which one out of these 2 ways, if any, is the correct way of structuring the brackets for random effect in 2x2 LMM. My IVs are `source` and `cnd` and the DV is `firstfix`.

```
one <- lmer(firstfix ~ source + cnd + source:cnd + 
    (1 + source + cnd | object) + (1 + cnd | subj) + 
    (1 + source:cnd | object), together, REML = FALSE)

two <- lmer(firstfix ~ source + cnd + source:cnd + 
    (1 + cnd | object) + (1 + source | object) + 
    (1 + cnd | subj) + (1 | subj) + (1 + source:cnd | object), 
        together, REML = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr** you almost certainly need to simplify your model ...

The important difference is that `lme4` treats separate random-effects terms (i.e. terms written in separate parenthesized chunks)  as independent.  For the sake of illustration, suppose that `source` and `cnd` are both categorical (factors), and that `source` has 2 levels and `cnd` has 3 levels.

```
(1 + source + cnd | object) + (1 + cnd | subj) + (1 + source:cnd | object)
```

This will give rise to a block-diagonal variance-covariance matrix with 3 blocks: the first has (1 + (2-1) + (3-1))=4 rows/cols, the second has (1+(3-1))=3 rows/cols, and the final one has 6 rows/cols. There will be a total of (4*5/2 + 3*4/2 + 6*7/2) = 37 variance-covariance parameters, which is **extremely** unlikely to be identifiable from anything but a gigantic data set. In addition, the first and third terms will definitely be confounded, because the raw interaction component in the third term will expand to terms that are synonymous with the main effects in the first term. The intercept terms will also be confounded between the two `object`-grouped terms (first and third).

```
(1 + cnd | object) + (1 + source | object) + 
(1 + cnd | subj) + (1 | subj) + (1 + source:cnd | object),
```

This assumes the terms are all independent, so we have block sizes of (3,2,3,1,6), or (6+3+6+1+21)= (again) 37 var-cov parameters. The intercept terms will be confounded between the terms with the same grouping variable.

Both of these models (1) contain redundant terms and (2) are overparameterized.  If you really want to follow Barr et al's "keep it maximal" advice, then use

```
(source*cnd|object) + (cnd|subj)
```

(the first term is equivalent to `(1+source+cnd+source:cnd|object)`), which will give you blocks of (6,3) or 27 parameters.

There's a lot more to say here: look e.g. at rejoinders of Vashishth and Bates to Barr et al., and the [RePsychLing](https://github.com/dmbates/RePsychLing) project.

Comment: Is this what was meant by the "rejoinder"? https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04967

Comment: yes: one of three refs listed in the README here: https://github.com/dmbates/RePsychLing